# How to disable remaining radio buttons if a specific radio button is checked?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, radio-button

I have the following bit of code generated by WooCommerce to display available shipping options:

```
<ul id="shipping_method">
<li>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate5" value="flat_rate:5" class="shipping_method"  checked='checked' />
<label for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate5">Call 386-410-4757 for Shipping Quote</label>                  </li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_wf_shipping_uspsd_express_mail" value="wf_shipping_usps:D_EXPRESS_MAIL" class="shipping_method"  />
<label for="shipping_method_0_wf_shipping_uspsd_express_mail">Priority Mail Express&#8482; (USPS): <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>22.95</span></label>                    </li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_wf_shipping_uspsd_priority_mail" value="wf_shipping_usps:D_PRIORITY_MAIL" class="shipping_method"  />
<label for="shipping_method_0_wf_shipping_uspsd_priority_mail">Priority Mail&#0174; (USPS): <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>6.45</span></label>
</li>
</ul>
```

What I need to be able to do is disable radio buttons 2 and 3 if the first radio button is selected.

I have tried this to no avail:

```
$('.shipping_method').click(function(){
   if(this.value == 'flat_rate:5' && this.checked){
       console.log($('input[value=wf_shipping_usps:D_EXPRESS_MAIL], input[value=wf_shipping_usps:D_PRIORITY_MAIL]'));
        $('input[value=wf_shipping_usps:D_EXPRESS_MAIL], input[value=wf_shipping_usps:D_PRIORITY_MAIL]').prop('disabled', true);
   }
   else{
      $('.shipping_method').not(this).prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Cynthia

Comment: Given that only 1 radio button can be selected from the named group, making the others disabled seems a little redundant - and annoying for your users as they won't be able to change their selection if they mis-click.

Comment: It needs to be done. I have a handful of products in Woocommerce where shipping cannot be calculated online so they need to call for shipping. For those products only, Call for Shipping appears as a shipping option.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce loads many things by AJAX, which means you need to use event delegation.

Further, you may misunderstand what `this` represents inside of a jQuery function, so I've reworked a few of your checks.

Lastly, you want ALL other inputs disabled, so rather then identifying them specifically, I've modified the code to disable ALL but the one that is required:

```
// WordPress loads jQuery in noConflict mode, so
// First be sure you can use the $ by wrapping inside of a
// noConflict-safe document ready
jQuery(function($) {
    // Event delegation
    $(document).on('click', '#shipping_method input', function() {
       // Use jQuery .val() and jQuery .is() to check if it's the correct item
       if( $(this).val() == 'flat_rate:5' && $(this).is(':checked') ) {
           $('input.shipping_method').not('[value="flat_rate:5"]').prop('disabled', true);
       } else {
           $('input.shipping_method').not('[value="flat_rate:5"]').prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', false);
       }
    });
});
```

**If you have problems**, be sure to check your browser's developer console, and to report as much detail about the problem back, otherwise it's impossible to help.